# Parsing JSON String with data classes

Tags: android, json, kotlin, data-class

After running the following line of code trying to pass a JSON string:

```
        var test = String(tempstore, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"))

        var gson = Gson()
        var testmodel = gson.fromJson(test, AuthoriseReq::class.java)
```

The JSON String is as follows :

```
{
  "transaction": {
    "id": "5f9a1239-0bdc-4ad6-84e0-f685cfa836f9",
    "timestamp": "2019-07-04T08:42:37.9830577+02:00"
  },
  "user": {
    "username": "trt",
    "passwordHash": "juju"
  },
  "terminal": {
    "terminalId": "juju",
    "site": {
      "id": "juju"
    }
  }
}
```

The data class are as follow, also to note is that I have included empty constructors in my data classes:

```
 data class AuthoriseReq(
            @SerializedName("transaction") val transaction: Transaction,
            @SerializedName("user") val user: User,
            @SerializedName("terminal") val terminal: Terminal)
    {
        constructor() : this(Transaction(), User(), Terminal())
    }


 data class Terminal(
            @SerializedName("terminalId") var terminalId: String,
            @SerializedName("site") var site: Site)
            {
             constructor() : this("",  Site())
            }

    data class Transaction(
            @SerializedName("id")   var id: String,
            @SerializedName("timestamp")   var timestamp:DateTime)
    {
        constructor(): this("", DateTime())
    }

data class Site(
        @SerializedName("id")   var id: String)
{
    constructor():this("")
}

data class User(
        @SerializedName("username")   var username: String ,
        @SerializedName("passwordHash")   var passwordHash : String )
{
    constructor(): this("","")
}
```

However, I keep on getting the following error when the JSON parsing is attempted :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 74 path $.transaction.timestamp
```

Comment: please see my answer &  please accept my answer, if it works for you. Thanks.

Comment: @ahmedaljubair will do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following

```
@SerializedName("timestamp")   var timestamp:DateTime)
```

with

```
@SerializedName("timestamp")   var timestamp : String )
```

This should resolve the error since `"2019-07-04T08:42:37.9830577+02:00"` is a String in the provided JSON string.